# Running Map Reduce task from another java process

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MR job ready.
I was running the task by calling `./bin/hadoop jar jarname` till now.

Now I have to run the same MR job from another java process. How can I do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ProcessBuilder if you exactly want to run using `hadoop jar` from an external java program.

```
 ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder("hadoop jar...");
 // Start the process and wait for it to finish. 
 Process process = processBuilder.start();

 //Read output
 InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
 String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
 }

 int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
 System.out.println("Job finished with status: " + exitStatus);
```

Comment: Will this give me Hadoop MR task execution status??

Comment: Yeah, please try it out. You can see, I'm printing the input stream.

Comment: Ok will do it.. Thanks a ton :)